# How are Windows SysInternal Utilities Licensed?

Tags: windows, license, sysinternals, sdelete

Specifically I want to know about [SDELETE by Mark Russinovich](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete). I didn't find any license attached, although he holds a Copyright for it..

I want to know because I want to distribute it in my own software. What are the license terms? Can I freely distribute it?

Comment: Doesn't the program force you to read the license terms the first time you run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Sysinternals web page has links to the software license and also a
license FAQ page at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/license-faq

The answer to your main question is "No".

> Q: May I distribute Sysinternals utilities in my software, on my
> website, or with my magazine?
>
> A: No. We are not offering any distribution licenses, even if the 3rd
> party is distributing them for free. We encourage people to download
> the utilities from our download center where they can be assured to
> get the most recent version of the utility.